# Where are the remaining Angels?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

We know in one of the episodes while Goku, Vegeta, Whis and Beerus sat down to eat, Whis stated that there were 18 Universes before and Zeno erased 6 Universes while he was in a bad mood.

After the Zen Exhibition match, we know for a fact that if Zeno were to erase a universe, even the gods, The kaioshin and hakaishin would also be erased. We also know that the angels are not related to the universe and their duty is to only serve the god of destruction, which is again mentioned by Whis when Beerus questioned as to why he wouldn't get erased.

It was also mentioned by Shin during the Future Trunks arc that if Beerus were to die, Whis were to leave the universe as his sole duty is to only serve Beerus.

Based on these events, shouldn't there exist 6 more angels of the erased Universes? Why aren't they watching the tournament of power (When the exempted universes are watching the same)? We know these angels don't cease to exist once their universe is erased as we see some of the angels of the erased universes seated and watching the tournament of power.

What are your thoughts on the same?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to present my personal viewpoint regarding this question.

Firstly, there is a common assumption that just like Whis serves Beerus, Daishinkan also serves Zeno and therefore by this analogy, just like Whis is stronger than Beerus, Daishinkan *"could"* be stronger than Zeno. The problem with this analogy is it doesn't consider the differences regarding the services provided by the Angels and the Grand Priest.

Whis serves as a mentor trains Beerus in combat. But Zeno is not a fighter. So there is no need for Daishinkan to train Zeno. Thus Daishinkan plays a role which could be considered akin to a ***secretary/butler/advisor/minister*** to Zeno.

Now since Daishinkan is Whis's father and much much stronger than Whis, the question is **Why would Daishinkan serve the Omni-king if not to train him?**

The only plausible explaination then would be that he was created to serve Zeno in an advisory role *(that is the Grand Priest's purpose)*.

Secondly, nowhere in Dragonball Super it is mentioned that the Angels are indestructible or free from Zeno's wrath. It is only mentioned that *the angels will not be wiped out after the TOP.*

**Why?**

Maybe because, Zeno didn't feel like it.

Or maybe Daishinkan talked him out of it.

Maybe the other angels are also related to Daishinkan and he doesn't want to see his kin erased like the previous 6 universes, so he persuades Zeno.

Maybe the angels have been kept alive because there is a chance Zeno might ressurect all the wiped universes.

We don't know. We only know that there are too many maybe's here and no definite answer. The only safe option here is to assume that the *previous angels were also probably erased along with the previous 6 out of 18 universes* but this time the remaining angels have been spared this fate.